# Errors in Executing While loop

Tags: r

I am trying to read a random data from a dataset in while loop but I'm getting errors, can anyone here help me?

How to calculate the percentage of points in the sample that are greater than 100?
I tried following method

```
dataset = 1:100
i=0
while(dataset[i] > condition) #compare every value in dataset 
{
  
    percent_age= dataset[i] + percent_age
    i=i+1
    if(i=100)
    {break}
}
```

But it gives me only errors.

Comment: It's very unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish here. But if you have a vector of numbers, and you just want to know what proportion of those numbers are greater than a value (say 100), you need to do something like this: `dataset <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace = TRUE); length(dataset[dataset > 100])*100 / length(dataset)` (as an example).

Comment: @Dunois Or `mean(dataset > 100)*100`. But I'm voting to close because the question's code is **not R code**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the posted code is not R code, the asker should first read an introductory text on R.

Comment: @RuiBarradas there really needs to be a "newcomer" tag. I don't mind helping this person, I just wish they'd explain themselves properly.

Comment: @Dunois I would answer too but `dataset(i)` as an indexing operation and the comment char `'\\'` show a need for very basic learning first.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I agree--and that's ground the OP has to cover. But there is stuff we can help them with that might make the burden manageable (like showing them how they can solve the problem if they cover the prerequisites first). But I digress: let's see if the OP responds at all to begin with.

Comment: @Dunois well I am beginner in R.. but I want to execute a vector(dataset) like array in C++. I want to read values of vector one by one,
for example if value of dataset[1] is equal to  let's say 10, add value of that specific value in vector so later i can calculate their percentage from there summation.

Comment: By "calculate their percentage from there summation." are you referring to calculating what percentage of `dataset` is equal to 10 (following your example)? (E.g., `dataset` has 10 values, 5 of them are > 10, so 50%.) Or do you want the sum of these values divided by the sum of all values in the vector? I apologize, but I am confused.

Comment: @Dunios well I realize I was complicating the solution.. it can done be simply with mean(dataset > 10)* 100 which was replied by RuiBarradas though his way of replying was quite rude, either one want to share knowledge or not , why to complicate things and deliver sermons when you are not asked,  anyway thanks to u Dunios I got my answer.. I am not R programmer I was just doing my statics assignment. and got stuck with loops..

Comment: @Dunois -> percentage=mean(Random_Number>condition) * 100
# calculating percentage of Random number greater than 150/2 then calculating mean and multiplying * 100

Comment: @Anonyms I see. I don't think RuiBarradas meant to be rude to you. It's just that everyone here is volunteering their time and effort, and it doesn't help if things aren't clear right from the get go. And I suppose the frustration of having to deal with that builds up over time, and you get tired of it; hence--I suspect--the curt response. But I am glad you figured out your solution!! I hope you finish(ed) your assignment successfully. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

The `while` statement is evaluated before anything in the body, so the first time it is evaluated `i` is equal to 0 and so `dataset[i]` is `dataset[0]` which is an empty object (vector of length 0), you also have not defined `condition` in the code that you give us.  So `while` is looking of a single logical value, but you are giving it the result of comparing a zero-length vector to an undefined value.  That is going to give at least one error.

You can fix that by starting `i` at 1 and defining `condition` before the `while`.

In your `if` statement you have `i=100`, that is setting `i` to `100`, to compare (and return a logical) it should be `i == 100`.

Because R can be used interactively, it tries to evaluate code as early as possible, therefore it is best to put the opening curly bracket `{` on the same line as the keywords like `if` and `while`.

A couple of nit-picky things that probably will not resolve errors, but could help for better programming in the future:

Use more whitespace within lines: `i = i + 1` can be easier to read than `i=i+1` and mistakes like `i=100` vs `i == 100` are easier to catch when whitespace is used appropriately.

I find the arrow assignment in R `i <- 1` reads easier and lessens chances of confusing different uses of `=`, so I would recommend using it for all assignments.